# error inflating android design widget when using proguard

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-proguard

getting

"Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout"

when app run through proguard with 
minifyEnabled true 
 and 
shrinkResources true

works fine sans proguard...

Comment: this is using androidSupportVersion=25.1.0 ...

.

`compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${androidSupportVersion}"
   compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:${androidSupportVersion}"
   compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${androidSupportVersion}"
   compile "com.android.support:design:${androidSupportVersion}"`

Comment: `compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${androidSupportVersion‌​}"`

`compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:${androidSupportVer‌​sion}"`

`compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${androidSupportVersion}"`

`compile "com.android.support:design:${androidSupportVersion}"`

Comment: let me know if there's any other things you'd want details on...

Answer (score 0):

only solution i could find was setting

shrinkResources false

but maybe there is a better answer?